# Setting range for Integer in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I don't want to allow negative numbers to be entered for an integer field in Rails Admin.  How can I constrain this on the front end?

Rails Admin doesn't seem to read in my validations from the model, and yet there doesn't seem to be a way in its DSL to specify it either.  Here's my model:

```
#  capacity:integer
class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :capacity, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }
```

I see that RailsAdmin [uses the number_field helper](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types/integer.rb#L12), which [has this option](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag).  But it's unclear to me how I can pass options to that..

Comment: Its weird that your model validation is not respected. What happens if you try something like this? `validates : capacity, inclusion: { in: 0..100 }`?

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam are you sure that RailsAdmin even reads validations other than `presence`?

Comment: can you try my answer? `validates_numericality_of(:capacity, greater_than: 0)`

Comment: looks like different types of validation works for RailsAdmin along with this: `validates_numericality_of `. See here for more examples: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/dcb774d7a5629ae129436669f43be63adc455a49/spec/dummy_app/app/active_record/draft.rb#L5-L10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
validates_numericality_of(:capacity, greater_than: 0)
```

There are some examples of `validates_numericality_of` [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/dcb774d7a5629ae129436669f43be63adc455a49/spec/dummy_app/app/active_record/draft.rb#L5-L10).